# How to get Header information from wp-api in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-services

I am working with a project in Angular 5 and consuming wp-api. With the help of api I showed data in Grid and apply dependent dropdowns.
For the purpose of pagination I need to get header information I tried but I cannot solved the issue. With the help of below query i send to get different information from api with the single query.
How do I get Header information.

```
 return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + this.apiUrl + '?per_page=100&page=' + page_number + '&filter[meta_value][abc]='+abc+'&filter[meta_value][def]='+def+'&filter[meta_value][ghi]='+ghi);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
public Method () : Observable<HttpResponse<any>>  {
    return this.http.get<any>(`/api/what/ever`, 
    {observe: 'response'});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.from the response object you can get header info like status,status text,data.you can check with postman what are the information are append on the response message,Based on that you can customize your code.

```
 return this.http.get(this.url, options).map((response: Response) => response.status/statustext);
```